# $p$-adic valuation in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Assume $p$ is a prime number, $M$ be a non-negative integer and denote by $(\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z})^*$ the units of $\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z}$. Now consider the partition of $\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z}$ as the union of the following disjoint sets, $$\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z}=\cup_{m=0}^Mp^m(\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z})^*.$$
Define the function $f:\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\cap [0,M]$ by $f(x):=m$ if and only if $ x\in p^m(\mathbb{Z}/p^M\mathbb{Z})^*$ in the union above. The function $f$ resembles in a way the classical $p$-adic valuation, but obviously it is not the same: for example, $f(0)=M$ but $v_p(0)=\infty$. The connection is that $$f(x)=\min\{v_p(y):y\in \mathbb{Z}, y\equiv x \mod{p^M}\}.$$

**Question: Does the function $f$ have a standard terminology in algebra/number theory?**

Comment: I would call it a truncated $p$-adic valuation (but I don't set the standards).

Comment: To second Gerry Myerson's remark, a simpler formula for $f$ is $f(x)=\min(v_p(y),M)$ for any $y$ in the class $x$.

Comment: In terms of norms, what is standard is to pass the norm to the quotient. Say, for an abelian group $A$ endowed with a subadditive norm $N$ (e.g., a normed ring or a Banach space), and $B$ a subgroup of $A$, one would define, for $\pi:A\to A/B$ the projection, $N(x)=\inf_{a\in\pi^{-1}(x)}N(a)$. To be closer to your case, assume that $N$ is ultrametric, and that $B$ is a ball around zero. Then for every $x\in B/A$, if $x\neq 0$ then $N$ is constant on $\pi^{-1}(x)$. This is close (up to exponentiation) to your setting, except the value at zero, where you choose a supremum rather than an infimum.